# How to turn off debug log in library

Tags: android

I use MediaPlayer to play a mp3 file in my android code. My code is like this:

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    try {
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("File:///XXX/" + word + ".mp3"));
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, fileUri);
        mediaPlayer.start(); 
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.d("ErrorPlayingSound:", word);
        return 1;
    }
```

Every time I run this code, it go through without any exception but jumps out a Logcat info as: "D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side", and it plays the audio, and return 0 then.

As a result of this, I can only see a lots of this logs in Logcat and it is hard to find the debug info I need to notice.

I want to turn off the Log.d info when go to this part and turn on it after this part. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: One thing you can do is to use Log Filter to limit scope of what you want to see in debug screen

Comment: @Milanix: Thank you for you answer. This is not the exact solution I needed, but maybe this is the only way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter log information, you can use different log tag, or different colorful log message(other than d, choose e or v or w or i)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This looks like a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

To see just a specific tag log you can use Logcat -s "your TAG name"

Comment: Thank you @Sushil. This looks like a way to filter the log information created by library function.

Comment: @rml .. Every android log has a TAG name which the developer mentions. Like in your example case it is "MediaPlayer". So, this way can be used for any looging, not specifically for log information created by library function.